# How can I calculate summations of modulus expressions?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, summation

I know that the following holds true: $$\sum_{k=1}^n k = {n (n + 1) \over 2} $$

Can modulus expressions be simplified in similar ways?
For example:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (k\bmod x) = ?? $$

To be clear, when I say modulus I mean "the non-negative integer that occurs as the remainder when dividing b by a", where b and a for my purposes are two integers, and x is some integer $x \leq k$.

Comment: Is the second to be reduce mod $x$, or are they numbers being added as per ordinary rules of arithmetic? And try using \pmod instead of \mod.

Comment: Edited - thank you for the formatting tips. Not sure what the difference between \pmod and \mod implies.

Comment: You know it's equal to $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\bmod n$, right?

Comment: Well clearly not or I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: Depends. When you say "$a \bmod b$", do you mean
$${\text{the non-negative integer that occurs as the }\atop \text{remainder when dividing }b\text{ by }a}$$
or
$$\text{the element }\,a+b\mathbb{Z}\,\text{ of }\,\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: @complexist the first one.

Comment: Use \bmod not \pmod, sorry about that.

Comment: @tM-- Should the answer be reduced mod $x$, or could it be a number greater than $x$? And I'm assuming $x$ is an integer?

Comment: @NotNotLogical I don't know what reduced mod x means, but yes x is some integer $x \leq k$.

Comment: Can the answer be greater than $x$?

Comment: Yes - the modulus is happening within the summation.

Comment: @tM-- You do realise that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and not $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$, right?

Comment: @IvanLoh sorry for the mistake will edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think people are understanding the question correctly, so please comment if this is what you were looking for:

$$\bigg[(1+\cdots +(x-1)+0)+(1+\cdots +(x-1)+0)+\cdots \bigg]+(1+\cdots+ (n\bmod x)) \\ =\left\lfloor \frac{n}{x}\right\rfloor\big(1+\cdots+(x-1)\big)+(1+\cdots +(n\bmod x)) \\ =\left\lfloor \frac{n}{x}\right\rfloor\frac{x(x-1)}{2}+\frac{(n\bmod x)(n\bmod x+1)}{2}$$

---

**Example.** Let's consider the case of $n=7$ and $x=3$: $$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{7}(k\bmod 3)&=(1\bmod 3)+(2\bmod 3)+(3\bmod 3)+(4\bmod 3)+\cdots \\ &=\Big[(1+2+0)+(1+2+0)\Big]+(1) \\ &=2\cdot (1+2)+(1) \\ &=\left\lfloor \frac{7}{3}\right\rfloor(1+2)+(1)\end{align}$$

Comment: Aha. That's precisely what I was about to comment.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused, where did the first term come from?

Comment: @tM-- $1\bmod x=1$, $2\bmod x=2$, ... $x-1\bmod x=x-1$, $x\bmod x=0$, then we repeat. $x+1\bmod x=1$, $x+2\bmod x=2$, ...

Comment: @tM-- Cheers!  .

Comment: @NotNotLogical after some thought I'm not sure if I'm convinced that I understand sorry. Why are there so many sums?

Wouldn't just the last term of the first line be sufficient? 
ex: $1 + ... + n \bmod x$

Comment: @tM-- I have edited with an example. Do you see why the formula works? Write out the sum in total if you still don't get it. You will see that it keeps repeating a pattern, until the end (where it gets a bit weird). **The last term would be sufficient only if we have $n<x$.**

Comment: Yes you're right - thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

You can always just compute the answer without modulus and then take the modulus afterward, so I assume you're asking whether it's possible to do all the arithmetic under modulus. Consider if $x = 2$. Then you can't divide by $2$, and you know that either $k$ or $k+1$ is even but you don't know if they are divisible by $4$, so you don't know whether your answer $\mod x$ should be $1$ or $0$. So no, you can't just do the arithmetic $\mod x$ for arbitrary $x$ to compute the formula. I do believe you can do it for ODD $x$, if you compute the inverse of $2 \mod x$.

Comment: Thanks - I do have a particular x in mind, so I will just edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle {}\,\sum_{k=1}^n (k\bmod x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(k-x\left\lfloor\frac{k}{x}\right\rfloor\right)=\sum_{k=1}^nk-x\sum_{k=1}^n\left\lfloor\frac{k}{x}\right\rfloor$

$\displaystyle {}\qquad\qquad\qquad = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}-x\left\lfloor\frac{n}{x}\right\rfloor\left(n+1-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{x}\right\rfloor\right)$

**Example.** Let's consider the case of $n=7$ and $x=3$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^7 (k \bmod 3)=\frac{7(7+1)}{2}-3\left\lfloor\frac{7}{3}\right\rfloor\left(7+1-\frac{3}{2}-\frac{3}{2}\left\lfloor\frac{7}{3}\right\rfloor\right)=7$$