# Compute summation of modules expression?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, summation, modular-arithmetic

This question is an extension of the following question:
[How can I calculate summations of modulus expressions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800746/how-can-i-calculate-summations-of-modulus-expressions)

In particular, what I want to look at is the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^n(pk\pmod{q})$$ where $p,q\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ can be assumed to be coprime but it would be best if solved in the fullest generality. In the above expression, $n$ is a variable, $p,q$ are fixed, and $a\pmod{b}$ means taking the representative set $\{0,1,2,...,b-1\}$. For example, $7\pmod{3}=1$ is the only value we agree upon and $7\pmod{3}\neq -2$.

The problem with this is that the list of representatives are permuted by $p$ and hence the methods presented in the initial link are no longer valid.

It would be nice if we can come up with a closed form, but a really tight upper bound of the expression also works.

Comment: This is subtracting some number of multiples of $q$ from the sum of $pk$. The question is how many? There's roughly $\frac{q}{p}$ terms where we don't subtract anything, $\frac{q}{p}$ terms where we subtract one copy of $q$, etc. Getting this exact feels like measuring the spacing of multiples of $p$ and multiples of $q$. Also note that assuming $p,q$ coprime doesn't lose generality: just divide a general sum by the GCD, solve it, then multiply back.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be $\frac{p \cdot n \cdot (n+1)}{2} \operatorname{mod} q$?

Answer (score 1):

Let the sequence $1p, 2p, 3p, ... qp, ..., np$. This shows that there are some multiples of $qp$, or $1qp, 2qp, ..., rqp$. Thus we can assume $r$ be the largest number such that $rq<n$. We can calculate that the number of cycles are $\lfloor\frac {n} q\rfloor$. The remaining numbers are $rq\mod n$.

We assume that for some integer $m_1, m_2$, such that $m_1p\equiv k\;(\mod q)$ and $m_2p\equiv k\;(\mod q)$. By adding up the two equations we have $(m_1-m_2)p\equiv0\;(\mod q)$. We know, for every prime $p,q$, they are coprime. This means that only for $|m_1-m_2|\;\bigg|q$. This tells us that in the sets of number $0p, 1p,2p,3p,...qp$, the modulo of the numbers are always different.

As we take the modulo when $0\leq r\leq q$, thus for every set of numbers $1p, 2p, ..., qp$, their modulo is $0, 1, 2, ..., q-1$, the total sum of them is $$\lfloor \frac {n} q\rfloor\sum_{i=1}^{q-1}i=\frac 1 2\lfloor \frac {n} q\rfloor q(q-1)$$

Case 1: $p< q$, thus we can roughly calculate the modulo by hand.
Case 2: $p> q$, we can assume $p=q+a$ for some integer $a$, we can also know that most of the value of $a$ is even as mostly of the prime numbers are odd. Then, for some integer $\alpha$, $\alpha p=\alpha(q+a)=\alpha q+\alpha a\equiv\alpha a\;(\mod q)$. Thus the entire summation can be evaluated as follow:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n pk\mod q\equiv \frac 1 2\color{red}{\lfloor \frac {n} q\rfloor}\color{blue}{ q(q-1)}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-rq}ia\mod q=\frac 1 2\color{red}r\color{blue}{(q^2-q)}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-rq}ia\mod q$$

Feel free to leave a comment if there're mistakes.

Comment: It seems like p<q is exactly the case I needed for either a closed-form formula or a very tight upper and lower bound on the sum (it must be better than the one you get using rearrangement inequality)... To put in context, I want to compute bounds on $\frac{q-1}{2}\{n/q\}-\frac{1}{q}\sum_{k=1}^n pk\pmod{q}$ where $\{x\}=x-\rm{floor}(x)$. Hence I only care for 0<n<q, and compute by hand is far away from good enough since I don't know the values in advance. Anyhow, I suppose you answered the original question so I will give you upvote and bounty.

Comment: There MAY be a better formula to this question, it is because for amy value $p$ and $q$, the remainder MAY have certain sequences.